# pyodbc create table with hypen in database name not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

Using python pyodbc, I am able to fetch/update/delete from a table to a given database `xyz-abc-a-sqldb` but when I am trying to create a table it is returning below error.

```
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Below is my sample code

```
        server = 'xyz-platform.database.windows.net'
        database = 'xyz-abc-a-sqldb'
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:'+server+',1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID=yyyyy;PWD=xxxxxxx')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = f"CREATE TABLE xyz-abc-a-sqldb.[dbo].[mytable] ([NAME][varchar](max) NULL)"
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            conn.rollback()
        conn.close()
```

Note:

1. In the query as my database name is not following the standard naming convension[which we can't modify] so I tried with `xyz-abc-a-sqldb` or "xyz-abc-a-sqldb" or [xyz-abc-a-sqldb] still not working.
2. DB connection is fine and user is having the permission to create table

I tried to access my database name in different way in the code like  `xyz-abc-a-sqldb` or "xyz-abc-a-sqldb" or [xyz-abc-a-sqldb] but nothing working

The root cauase is the non standard database name but resolution I am not able to find, This is what I am expecting.